# How to insert non-English reference numbers in Office 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard, microsoft-office, language, cross-reference

I am using Word 2010 (Professional Plus) on a Win 7 machine. I am typing a document in Tibetan, and I would like for the reference numbers (footnote and endnote numbers) to also be in Tibetan, but they are not, they are only in English (Arabic) characters. I have a similar problem with page numbers, which it would be great if ti could be fixed, but reference numbers is the more pressing concern.

I am using a Tibetan unicode font, and a third-party input system. I have Tibetan installed as an additional language in Office and I also have it installed as a language and keyboard in Windows, but I am NOT using the Windows Tibetan keyboard. However, I have tried to insert references while using the Win7 Tibetan keyboard and it still inserts Arabic characters.

My default language for the computer as well as Office is US English.

I have been able to find no help online at all, most of the times questions about non-English characters in Office don't have replies. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The best that I was able to achieve here was to use the "custom mark" option to insert each mark manually. i.e., I don't think there is a way to get automatic footnote numbering, unless you have a font that that has Tibetan digit glyphs at either the Unicode codepoints 0x30 - 0x39 (and I'm assuming that Tibetan digits works the same way as "Western digits") or some other set of codepoints that Word supports. You can try specifying the digits in Windows control panel, and the digit behaviour in Word Options, but AFAICS no combination does what you want. & what happens when you send your doc.?

Comment: Thanks. I did find one old legacy Tibetan font (non-Unicode) that does assign the Tibetan glyphs to the Unicode codepoints of the western glyphs, which works... but it means every notation has to be edited by hand (twice, once in the body and once in the note). The difficulty is the legacy font is a wacky size, so the font needs to be changed, the size changed, and then the line position raised a few points. It becomes tedious when the footnotes run into the triple digits... A similar tedium when using the custom mark option. Thanks for the suggestion, though. I was hoping for an easier way...

Comment: I would be hoping for an easier way, too. Unfortunately, even the way that display of "national characters sets means that unless you use the glyph codepoints that you really need, it is difficult to guarantee that readers of your document with different Windows and Word settings will see your document as intended. (I intended to spell that out in my previous remark but run out of sapce,and time).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use VBA to replace all the footnote references with a sequence of references using the Tibetan glyphs. I think the following would do this for the footnotes, assuming that you want every footnote to be numbered this way, and the numbering is continuous throught the whole document. But if you wanted to see the correct numbering all the time, you would have to run this macro every time you inserted, deleted or resequenced a footnote.

```
Sub replaceFootnoteRefsbyTibetanSequence()
Dim fsource As Word.Footnote
Dim ftarget As Word.Footnote
Dim lng As Long
Dim rsource As Word.Range
Dim rtarget As Word.Range
With ActiveDocument
  For lng = 1 To .Footnotes.Count
    Set rtarget = .Footnotes(lng).Reference.Duplicate
    rtarget.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Set ftarget = rtarget.Footnotes.Add(rtarget, strTibetan(lng))
    rtarget.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleFootnoteReference).NameLocal
    ftarget.Range.FormattedText = .Footnotes(lng).Range.FormattedText
    .Footnotes(lng).Delete
    Set ftarget = Nothing
    Set rtarget = Nothing
  Next
End With

End Sub

Function strTibetan(theNumber As Long) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As String
s = ""
For i = 1 To Len(CStr(theNumber))
  s = s & ChrW(AscW(Mid(CStr(theNumber), i, 1)) - AscW("0") + &HF20)
Next
strTibetan = s
End Function
```

Something similar would doubtless be possible with endnotes. Things might be harder if there is per-page or per-section numbering.

Comment: Thanks, bibadia, I will try it. My VBA knowledge is poor enough that writing this on my own would take more time than changing them by hand, so thanks!

Comment: Just an update - I realized that of the 215 footnotes, spread out among 21 sections, the numbers are not continuous. So that means the VBA wouldnt work. However, I figured out the quick and easy way to make it happen. I just did a find and replace, with ^f in the find field and ^& in the replace field. I specified the font size for the find which allowed me to distinguish between the footnotes in the body and the actual footnotes at the bottom of each page, and then I adjusted the font and font size as needed... so I was able to replace all of them with just a few clicks, less than a minute.